# Custom module in C/C++, can't compile in x64 platform

Tags: c++, apache, visual-studio, module, 64-bit

I am working on a custom module for Apache 2.3 in Windows. I need to include some Apache libraries, libapr-1.lib, libaprutil-1.lib, libhttpd.lib. I set up the path in Visual Studio. It can compile in 32 bit platform without a problem. However, if I switch to x64 and compile (with same path settings), it complains can't find some functions from the Apache libraries.

For example

Error 3 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_ht_time

Error 4 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_log_error

Error 5 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ap_run_default_port

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: looks like you're missing a  link to a .lib file associated with a DLL you're using

Comment: The .dll and .lib on x64 are unrelated to x86. You need to get the 64-bit version of APR and set the paths accordingly.